# Handling failures with SmallRye Mutiny

Tags: java, quarkus, reactive, mutiny, smallrye

I am new to and learning reactive programming with Quarkus and mutiny.

My code is a basic block where I am playing around with all these new concepts. I am struggling to figure out how to achieve the returning of a different Uni type onFailure to what was given in the original Uni definition.

here are some additional details.

```
private Uni<Status> processSignal(final Signal signal) {
        return Uni.createFrom().item(signal)
            .map(signal -> "someRandomString".getBytes())
            .onFailure().recoverWithItem(Status.builder()
                .state("Signal Failed")
                .message("Your signal failed")
                .build())
            .onItem().transform(result -> Status.builder()
                .state("Signal Passed")
                .message("Your signal passed")
                .build());
    }
```

the code above will not work as the `onFailure` expects a byte array. How would I structure this so that I can use different types?

I have tried using `.transform()` and `.recoverWithUni()` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `map` gives you a `Uni<byte[]>` so the next operators expect items to be `byte[]`.

`recoverWithItem` takes a `Uni<T>` and returns a `Uni<T>`, so you need an extra `map`/`onItem().transform()` to go from `byte[]` to `Status`.

Actually in your code it's not clear why you go from a `Signal` to `byte[]` to `Status`.

Comment: the use of byte is not relevant, this could be any other type. maybe a String etc but the concept remains  the same.

Comment: Yes so that's per the API design. If you want to move to other types you first need a transformation: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/2.3.1/tutorials/transforming-items/